# Java Bukkit Plugin "Cannot be resolved to a variable"

Tags: java, plugins, bukkit

I've two classes under the same package Class names are "TestPlugin" and "Pokemon". The error I get is in the class TestPlugin at line 7 where there's written "New Pokemon". The error is "Cannot be resolved to a variable". I want the TestPlugin to acces the code in Pokemon so it can be used. What should I do to fix this problem? New to bukkit plugin creation so don't make the answer too advanced please. "I don't own this code/plugin. I've it for educational purposes only!". If you wonder what bukkit libary I'm using, it's the recommended build "craftbukkit-1.6.4-R2.0".

TestPlugin's code:

```
package com.hotmail.marrunsilkeborg.plugins.testplugin;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;   

public class TestPlugin extends JavaPlugin{
    public void onEnable(){
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Pokemon, this);

    }
}
```

Pokemon's code:

```
package com.hotmail.marrunsilkeborg.plugins.testplugin;

import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockPlaceEvent;

public class Pokemon implements Listener{

    @EventHandler
    public void onBlockPlace(BlockPlaceEvent event){
        Player p = event.getPlayer();
        Block bp = event.getBlockPlaced();


        p.sendMessage("You've placed a " + bp.getType().toString());        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change line 7 to
    this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Pokemon(this), this);
also think about adding a on disable

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to call Pokemon's constructor, so use 
`new Pokemon()` with the parentheses.

As @Welsar55 mentioned, use `new Pokemon(this)` if you are referencing your plugin in the Pokemon constructor (common-practice for Java plugins), i.e. where your Pokemon constructor is:

```
public Pokemon(TestPlugin myPlugin) {
    this.plugin = myPlugin;
}
```